# Make a numbered list using format and loops in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I feel like this is a basic question/problem but I can't get it. I'm trying to number output to look like this:

```
1. Info1: 5 times
2. Info2: 2 times
3. Info3: 8 times
4. Info4: 9 times
```

Using this code:

```
    for i in range(0,10):
        for x in data:
            print "{0}. {1}: {2} times".format(i, x[0], x[1])
```

But it just prints everything 10 times. How do I get it to number each item like above?

The data looks like this:

```
[('Plants and Animals', 1347), ('Dr. Dog', 1198), ('The Dodos', 1176), ('Broken Social Scene', 1092), ('The Beatles', 1014)]
```

Comment: What does data look like?

Comment: Delete the `for i in xrange(0,10)` and make the `for x in data:` a `for i,x in enumerate(data):`, then think about why it printed everything ten times originally.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you x is list of tuples. You only need to loop one time.

```
x = [('Info1',5),('Info2',2), ('Info3',8),('Info4',9)]
for i in range(0,10):
    print "{0}. {1}: {2} times".format(i+1, x[i][0], x[i][1])
```

However using this you'll run into IndexError if x has less than 10 elements. So instead of use:

```
for i in range(0,10):
```

you can use:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
```

Or even simpler to use `enumerate`

```
data = [('Info1',5),('Info2',2), ('Info3',8),('Info4',9)]
for i,x in enumerate(data):
    print "{0}. {1}: {2} times".format(i+1, x[0], x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for 2 loops. Also you should use `i + 1` if you want the first outputted number to be 1

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    print "{0}. {1}: {2} times".format(i+1, data[i][0], data[i][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to loop over all the values of `data` then **you only need the inner loop** (`for x in data:...`).

So here it is:

```
 for x in data:
     print "{0}. {1}: {2} times".format(x[0], x[0], x[1])
```

or if x[0] is not gonna be always like 1,2,3...

```
 counter = 1
 for x in data:
     print "{0}. {1}: {2} times".format(counter, x[0], x[1])
     counter += 1
```

Now your problem is that you've added an extra outer loop (`for i in range(0,10)`) and now your code executes the inner loop 10 times (each time with a different value for i). But that's what you're asking from python to do with these extra lines.

To get it pretend you're the computer and start following the commands of your program (you may also use the python debugger to execute your code line by line -- it helps)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate).

```
for i, x in enumerate(data):
  print("{0}. {1}: {2} times".format(i, x[0], x[1]))
```